# Laravel Jobs: Can't delete file after queue processed

Tags: laravel, jobs

I just cant figure why is this happening. When I dispatch job which uploads file to my Amazon S3, I want to delete id and update relation (channel). Everything works but I cant delete the file. I cant delete the file even manually. Windows says some process is still using it. To delete it manually I have to end queue worker first. Wierd part is that file is uploaded o my S3, relation is updated in database and queue worker in terminal says job is processed. No failed or running jobs in the jobs table. Anyone know whats going on?

My Job handle below.

```
 public function handle()
{
    $path = storage_path() . "/uploads/" . $this->fileId;
    $fileName = $this->fileId . ".png";

    if(Storage::disk("s3images")->put("profile/" . $fileName, fopen($path, "r+"))){
        File::delete($path);
    }
    $this->channel->image_filename = $fileName;
    $this->channel->save();
}
```

Comment: perhaps try `File::delete($path.'.png');`

Comment: nope :-/  the file is stored without the extension. Extension is only used for S3 storage.

Comment: Worker does not end until script is done, so maybe try spawning new job (into queue) to delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
unlink($path)
```

It worked for me.